# MATLAB 2021b Installation error

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, matlab

The

```
sudo ./install
```

command does not open up the installer. The install file shows as an executable file. It asks for password and after that nothing, it keeps processing, but does not show any result. I use a Ubuntu 20.04.3 dual booted alongside with Windows in a HP Series 15 laptop.

I am trying to install the latest Matlab version R2021b.

Have already tried "sudo chmod -R 777 matlab_R2021b_glnxa64"

Comment: Switch to Xorg session first. Also note that you can run `./install` script with limited user rights. It will be installed into your home folder as the result. All you need would be addind its installation folder to `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue when installing MATLAB 2021b, Ubuntu 18.04. Installing it on x11 failed but was successful after switching to wayland. To know which session you are on run:

```
$ loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type
```

For more info on how to switch between x11 and wayland, check out https://www.maketecheasier.com/switch-xorg-wayland-ubuntu1710/